# Javascript - Trying to save lunr index to localstorage, can't load properly

Tags: javascript, json, lunrjs

I'm trying to create a search feature for my website, so I'm using lunr.js and it requires me to create an index and when I want to search, to load that index and search using it.

So, after I create my index, I need to convert it to JSON and load it later when I need to use it. I was thinking of using localStorage, so I save it in localStorage. But when I try to load the index back, it gives me a "cannot load un-registered function: undefined"

Relevant code:

```
var savedIndex = index.toJSON();
var workingLoad = lunr.Index.load(savedIndex);
console.log(workingLoad);

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('savedIndex', JSON.stringify(savedIndex));

var data = localStorage.getItem('savedIndex');
var nonWorkingLoad = lunr.Index.load(data); //Error here
```

Comment: It seems you are passing a `JSON` string to the `load` function. Convert the `JSON` string to an object, like `JSON.parse(data)` and then try feeding it to the `load` function.

Comment: yup that did it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @HectorBarbossa maybe consider adding your comment as an answer to this question?

Comment: where does lunr stores the index?